# App is crashing while swiping between tabbed fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

i try to implement a Recyclerview in my Fragment. Its working fine but if i swipe to fast between my first Fragment und my seccond Fragment its crashing --> see video. Here is the Error log:

```
08-06 14:59:06.346 4027-4103/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
08-06 14:59:06.358 4859-4885/? E/PackageLogInfoManager: checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@d696c32, packageNames: null
08-06 14:59:06.388 2416-2416/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
08-06 14:59:06.437 2416-2416/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
08-06 14:59:06.445 3069-3378/? E/InputReader: QEEXO fs_touch_up NULL, not calling FingerSense
08-06 14:59:06.575 2416-2416/? E/hwcomposer: setGpuBoost:228: Can't open /sys/class/devfreq/gpufreq/max_freq: Permission denied
08-06 14:59:06.935 2416-2416/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
08-06 14:59:09.525 3069-3385/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
08-06 14:59:10.708 14240-14240/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@0000000a@DynamiteLoader_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-06 14:59:10.841 14245-14245/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@data@com.google.android.gms@app_chimera@m@0000000b@GoogleCertificates_GmsCore_prodmnc_xhdpi_release.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-06 14:59:11.285 3069-4006/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
```

and here is my Fragment:

```
public class Events_Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
private static String url = "http://partypeople.bplaced.net/lola.php";
private static final int DATASET_COUNT = 60;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> testdata;

protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
protected Customlist_Events mAdapter;

protected String[] mDataset;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addData();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
    rootView.setTag(TAG);
    testdata = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    LinearLayoutManager lin = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(lin);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //new FetchDataTask().execute();
    mAdapter = new Customlist_Events(mDataset);
    // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Countdown finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return rootView;
}


public void addData(){

    mDataset = new String[DATASET_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < DATASET_COUNT; i++) {

        mDataset[i] = "name";

    }
}
```

here is my Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my Custom Adapter:

```
public class Customlist_Events extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Customlist_Events.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";

private String[] mDataSet;

/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using (custom ViewHolder)
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
            }
        });
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
 *
 * @param dataSet String[] containing the data to populate views to be used by RecyclerView.
 */
public Customlist_Events(String[] dataSet) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    // Create a new view.
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set."+mDataSet[position]);

    // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the contents of the view
    // with that element

    viewHolder.getTextView().setText(mDataSet[position]);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mDataSet.length;
}
```

}

it doesnt matter which data i try to show in my Recyclerview.
Regards

Comment: can you clear the error log and run your app, crash it, and post the error log at the time of crash?? because the current log doesn't help much

Comment: Sorry, here are the line i receive while crashing:

Comment: 08-06 15:17:26.664 2416-2416/? E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
08-06 15:17:26.851 2416-2416/? E/hwcomposer: setGpuBoost:228: Can't open /sys/class/devfreq/gpufreq/max_freq: Permission denied
08-06 15:17:27.201 4027-4263/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
08-06 15:17:27.201 4027-4263/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...

Comment: "see video" ... what video? Your error logs don't seem to have anything to do with your app. You say the issue between swiping between first fragment and second fragment, but there's no indication of where you have two fragments to switch between. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have a tabbed Activity project where i can swipe between three fragments

Comment: if i swipe between the start Fragment and the seccond fragment i can do this but if i swipe to fast its crashing